# Mysql bulk updates from local data infile

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a query like

```
 UPDATE table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) AND (t1.Version = t2.Version)
    SET t1.RR = 'abc'
    WHERE t1.id = bcd;
```

I have to run this for `1000`'s of values. For bulk inserts we have `load data infile` which does it in short time. Can we use the same for `update` as well ? Will it work with `join` on another table?
If not is there any other way as this takes a long time as of now.

Comment: Question: Do you have indices setup on all the join columns in `table2` (`id` and `Version`)?  If not, then adding indices should speed up the update substantially.

Comment: I didn't realize it was you :-)  ... I don't think it's possible to do a join during a bulk import operation.  But I think with indices you won't have a problem, unless you have say millions of records (or you need lightning fast speed, e.g. in a real time app).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :) ok will check on how to update indices!!!

Comment: @vks do you have the value that need to be updated in file?

Comment: @viki888 its in dict but writing to file is trivial :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen read smwer `INSERT and UPDATE statements take more time on tables having indexes where as SELECT statements become fast on those tables. The reason is that while doing insert or update, database need to insert or update index values as well.`

Comment: But you're not modifying `table2` in the operation, and hence its indices should not be changing.  But having a fast way to look up a record in `table2` should, from what I can see, speed up the join.  But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: To be clear here: I'm thinking don't put any indices on `table1`, since you'll always need a full table scan of it, but do put indices on `table2`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh right!!!!!!! missed that...thanx :)